# Unit vectors in spherical co-ordinate system

Tags: vectors, spherical-coordinates

I see that a vector can be described in spherical co-ordinates, with respect to it's cartesian co-ordinates as

$$ \mathbf{r}=r\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}\mathbf{\hat{x}}+r\sin{\theta}\sin{\theta}\mathbf{\hat{y}} + r\cos{\theta}\mathbf{\hat{z}}$$

So, the unit vector $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ is calculated by dividing the vector $\mathbf{r}$ by it's magnitude $r$.

$$ \mathbf{\hat{r}}=\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}\mathbf{\hat{x}}+\sin{\theta}\sin{\theta}\mathbf{\hat{y}} + \cos{\theta}\mathbf{\hat{z}}$$

But I am unsure as to how to get the other two unit vectors, $\mathbf{\hat{\theta}}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{\phi}}$.

Using the reasoning above I thought I could just add 90 degrees to either $\theta$ or $\phi$ to the $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ result to get the corresponding unit vector.  This reasoning gives me a correct result for $\mathbf{\hat{\theta}}$.  However, for the result I have been given, $\mathbf{\hat{\phi}}$ has only $\mathbf{\hat{x}}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ components.  Why is this?

Comment: Does this help: from $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{\theta}}$, compute $\mathbf{\hat{\phi}}$ as a vector cross product.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you.  Also, it helped to realise that whilst the reasoning works for $\mathbf{\hat{\theta}}$, it is not correct for $\mathbf{\hat{\phi}}$.  I had to spend some time waving chopsticks around to realise.